# Is audio.duration a fixed or growing value?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I've been searching for an answer to this, but fallen flat.

Is the value of the HTML5 audio/video attribute `duration` a growing number that inflates along with the buffering, or is it a precalculated metadata value that comes with the media data?

When testing this I only get one `durationchange` event call (except for Chrome who first sets duration to 0, then to the total media length), so I GUESS that the duration value is a fixed metadata attribute. But I don't want to take this for granted, as this really affects what approach I should use in the code structure.

Comment: You could test this a different way: `console.log()` the value in a `setInterval` loop as the content loads and plays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the HTML5 spec:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-duration)

> The `duration` attribute must return the time of the end of the [media resource](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#media-resource), in seconds, on the [media timeline](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#media-timeline). If no [media data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#media-data) is available, then the attributes must return the Not-a-Number (NaN) value. If the [media resource](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#media-resource) is not known to be bounded (e.g. streaming radio, or a live event with no announced end time), then the attribute must return the positive Infinity value.

Since a [media resource](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#media-resource) is, in the spec,

> the complete set of media data, e.g. the complete video file, or complete audio file

then the `duration` is a fixed value, not one that grows as the browser receives the media.

Comment: Which means that as soon as I have a non-zero value, then it's safe to use this as the total length. Super awesome, thanks a lot for your research!

Comment: No - the spec says nothing about zero. As soon as you have a non-`NaN` and non-Infinity value, you have a meaningful total length.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I ment as soon as I have a numerical non-zero value. Chrome still throws a duration=0 at me before getting the correct length.

Comment: That's odd. Seems like a bug.